# What (if any) is the proper hyphenation for the phrase "it's all too easy"?

Tags: grammar, hyphenation

Are any of the following correct?

> It's all too-easy
>   It's all-too-easy
>   It's all too easy

Explanation/citations would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Getting documents was [all too easy](http://www.theregister.co.uk/2014/02/10/getting_documents_all_too_easy_for_snowden/) for Snowden.

Comment: Is this for the new Star Wars movie?

Comment: Well, the answer is only all too easy.

Comment: Possible duplicate/ Closely related: https://english.stackexchange.com/a/150173/14666

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to hyphenate the phrase unless it is used either as a compound noun or as a compound adjective.

As a compound noun, it is likely to be a nickname, in which case, capitalise the initial letters:

- It's All-Too-Easy (as in names such as John-Paul, or Maria-Luisa)
- It's 'All Too Easy' (as a nickname) and It's All Too Easy (as a non-hyphenated name) would both also be acceptable.

As a compound adjective, it would need a determiner before it, e.g.,

- It's the all-too-easy solution to all our problems. Don't you believe it.

ADDITION:

In the plural, eg 'all-too-easy solutions' no determiner is needed, as Kris commented, below.

Comment: Yes, it's an [all too easy](http://www.nytimes.com/2006/02/06/technology/06link.html?pagewanted=print&_r=0) and not entirely fair game to play. (NYT)

Comment: Compound adjectives do not necessarily need a determiner before them. *All-too-easy solutions are always too easy to work*.

Comment: @Kris - thanks - I've updated to reflect your comment.

Answer (score 1):

There would be no hyphen involved. I assume you're thinking of the linking of two adjectives, but that's only when they come before a noun. If you want to read more rules about hyphens, read here:

http://www.grammarbook.com/punctuation/hyphens.asp